# Are there Bounty Hunters in Star Wars universe who work within the limits of the laws?

Tags: star-wars

Definitions of bounty hunter:

- Oxford: A person who pursues a criminal or fugitive for whom a reward is offered.
- Cambridge: Someone who searches for criminals or hunts animals in exchange for a reward.
- Collins: A bounty hunter is someone who tries to find or kill someone in order to get the reward that has been offered.
- Merriam-Webster: Someone who catches criminals who have not been caught by the police in exchange for a reward.
- Dictionary.com: A person who hunts outlaws or wild animals for the bounty offered for capturing or killing them.

None of the dictionaries say that a bounty hunter has to be a criminal. But, in *Star Wars*, all bounty hunters I see are criminals. They don't care about laws. They kill just about anyone in their way. They loot ships as their own declared reward.

Are there "good" bounty hunters in the *Star Wars* universe: ones who work within the limits of laws?

Comment: The main characters of the Star Wars: Aftermath series are essential Rebellion / New Republic bounty hunters looking for escaped, leftover Imperials. Much like Mossad / Nazi Hunters after WWII. Depending on definitions of "good" and "work within the limits of the law" this would be a canon example. Star Wars has also played fast and loose with definitions. Bounty Hunter often also equates to pirate (looting of ships)

Comment: In the Clone Wars series, there's a few episodes following young Boba Fett where he is rather heroic all while learing the ropes of the bounty hunter trade.

Comment: @NKCampbell If they did that to earn bounty/reward, then this can be answer.

Comment: Are we sure the bounty hunters we see _are_ breaking laws? (I'm aware that "good" isn't necessarily the same as "law-abiding" which is why I'm only addressing the latter). I mean, the ones who work for the Imperials are working for the _de facto_ government, and perhaps they have special dispensation to do all of the otherwise illegal things that they do.

Comment: In the original series, the "laws" are the laws of the Empire. Since the Empire is evil, and bounty hunters are part of enforcing the laws of the Empire, they are evil by association. Being a bounty hunter in the SW original trilogy is inherently evil because it is in service to an evil government.

Comment: Perhaps the better question might be whether any of them are portrayed as non-villainous?

Comment: re: the Imperial Hunters in the Aftermath series, it's ambiguous as to whether they are the only dedicated team the New Republic sends after Imperials or if the New Republic has multiple groups or open notices of who they want. Maybe someone else who can tolerate reading through those books again can make an answer of it. Just searching for that term and reading a bit of context around it made me not ever want to crack those open again ;)

Comment: IIRC bounty hunting was legal in the Republic as long as one did not violate any other laws (the target of a bounty might not be a person's head, after all... bounties on Stack Exchange certainly don't involve murder!)

Comment: @ToddWilcox Just because the Empire used bounty hunters sometimes doesn't mean the profession was evil. Bounty hunters were around before the Empire, so even if you could paint the entire profession with a single alignment (which you can't), it would be independent of the Empire's use of them.

Answer (score 7):

[Sugi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sugi_(bounty_hunter)) is noted as being honorable in her dealings although there was no love lost for the Jedi.

> Sugi was an honorable mercenary who would take jobs because she believed in them, not just because she would be paid. She was one for stopping in mid-battle to check on a comrade if they were hurt. She disliked the Jedi, quipping they were peacekeepers who failed to keep it during the Clone Wars, and was antagonistic towards Kenobi for implying she was only on Felucia for the credits, although he had initially refused to help the locals. However, after fighting alongside him, they developed a mutual respect.

That said, while she and her compatriots are listed as "bounty hunters", [it doesn't look they do all that much hunting for bounties](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThePiratesWhoDontDoAnything) (TVTropes link).

Comment: Just because you believe in something doesn't mean the job is still lawful. Also - isn't this just some wiki fan's opinion on her character?

Comment: @NKCampbell: The original question was about them being "good" rather than "lawful", so that's what I addressed. And the rest of the text of the wiki, as well as the episode description, seems to support that group of bounty-hunters being a moral group. *shrug* But I will leave people to vote as they will.

Comment: the question asks specifically: "Are there "good" bounty hunters in the Star Wars universe: *ones who work within the limits of laws?*", to me, the semicolon and text after is clarifying text on what OP defines as 'good' - I'm not inclined to downvote the answer, just feels a little loose as regards a good source and addressing what I felt the question was stating. *shrug* indeed :)

Comment: @NKCampbell - just to be completely fair: I made that edit (admittedly, made beofre FuzzyBoots posted his answer) - "Are there good bounty hunters in Star Wars universe who work within the limits of laws?" was the original sentence, which is (admittedly, very slightly) less clear.